# Usage of Fabric(Crashlytics) with IONIC project

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, crashlytics, google-fabric

I would like to integrate crashlytics with my IONIC project and for that I was searching any official SDK/Plugin support provided by crashlytics.

I have found two plugins :
https://github.com/4sh-projects/cordova-crashlytics-plugin
https://github.com/sarriaroman/FabricPlugin

But this plugins having also some open issues with Android and iOS.

Is there any other plugin or sdk is available for the same?

Also I would like to know whether it is better to use crashlytics for IONIC type of hybrid project?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my issue.

There was no required to use any plugin.

I have installed Fabric application on Mac machine for iOS build and Fabric plugin inside Android studio for Android build.

Then on the the Fabric, we have to login using valid credentials and then in UI wizard there are very few steps to follow to integrate Crashlytics within our Android and iOS project.